# How to add space between a row items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to put a space between Elements with `@Html.DisplayFor`. I know the DisplayFor is a property "bound", but in this case I can't modify.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @{
                foreach (var t in item.ProcessDataDefinitions)
                {                      
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => t.Name )
                    @Html.Label(" : ")
                    foreach (var gg in t.Values)
                    {                          
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => gg.Value)
                    }                       
                }
            }
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Ir", "../Process/Show", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Andamento", "../Process/ViewTracker", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>


    </tr>
}
```

So in the second `foreach` I want to create a little space between the property `Name` and `Value`, I tried to use `@Html.Label(" : ")` the : appears but doesn't give some space.

Comment: There's no need to modify your HTML, you should be using CSS for layout and styling. For example, add `padding-right: 10px` to your input.

Comment: @DavidG but you can't, or at least shouldn't, use CSS to add whitespace to your HTML. (OP means a space character)

Comment: @MindSwipe I'm pretty sure OP just wants a gap and is trying to achieve it with a whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to just put a gap between your elements, then you should use CSS, for example:

```
<div class="model-name">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => t.Name )
</div>

foreach (var gg in t.Values)
{     
    <div class="model-value">                     
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => gg.Value)
    </div>
}
```

And your CSS could be something like this:

```
.model-name { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.model-value { 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is a runnable demo to demonstrate my point (with coloured borders to emphasise the positions):

```css
.model-name { 
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.model-value { 
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="model-name">
        ModelName
</div>

<div class="model-value">                     
    Model Value 1
</div>
<div class="model-value">                     
    Model Value 2
</div>
<div class="model-value">                     
    Model Value 3
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `<text>` element for this purpose:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => t.Name )<text>" : "</text>
```

I think you can also use the `@:` as another alternative. You can get more information here: [Razor’s @: and `<text>` syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

It can be even more simple, you don't need any extra tags(extra tags makes your page heavier):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => t.Name) :
```

you can also use the `&nbsp;` like:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(model => t.Name)&nbsp;:
```